# MySQL: How to display orders placed after a certain date with subqueries.

Tags: mysql, subquery

My instructor wants me to use a subquery to do the following:

"Display the company name for any company that placed an order on or after Feb. 5, 2006."

So far I have:

```
SELECT customer_code
FROM orders
WHERE order_date > '2006-02-05';
```

This produces the results, but it's not with a subquery. How can I display this with a subquery?

Comment: Hint: Try to use the query you have in conjunction with a query off of the Customers (or Company or Client) table.

Comment: it doesn't quite produce the results.  where is company name?

Comment: company 'name' is in the 'customers' table.

Comment: and that's what you use the subquery to find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT company_name FROM customers
WHERE id IN 
(SELECT customer_code FROM orders
 WHERE order_date > '2006-02-05');
```

The sub query SELECTs the customer_code FROM the order table WHERE the order_date is after the 2006-02-05. This is then used to SELECT the company_name FROM the customers table WHERE id is found IN the sub query.

There are also other ways:

```
SELECT company_name 
FROM orders, customers
WHERE customer_code = customers.id 
and order_date > '2006-02-05';


SELECT company_name 
FROM customers
JOIN ORDERS
ON customer_code = customers.id 
AND order_date > '2006-02-05'; 


SELECT company_name 
FROM customers
JOIN ORDERS
ON customer_code = customers.id 
WHERE  order_date > '2006-02-05';
```

Last queries are without sub queries. The option using a join is probably the most common form. 
[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af4a1/1)

Comment: Thank you thank you, this makes so much sense now! The join was initially the only thing making sense and I think the problem for me is getting used to the multiple layers with subqueries. Thanks again!

Comment: @FionaCat86 glad that I could help. You can close / delete your duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a query which will get you the `customer_code`'s for certain orders. But now you also need to get the names of all the customers with those `customer_code`'s. Here's a few tips,

1. How would you get the name of a customer if you have just their `customer_code`? Write that as it's own simple query, having nothing to do with orders.
2. Now how can you get the name of customers if you have more than one `customer_code`? Modify the query from #1 to do this.
3. Finally, you already have the query to get lots of `customer_code`'s (from your question) for various orders, so use that query instead of the `customer_codes` from #2. The query from your question becomes the subquery.

Note you could also achieve the same output by using a JOIN, but you specifically asked about subquery.

Comment: Unfortunately I still have no idea how to do this. Everything I'm trying is coming out as an error. I know I need to use the subquery to somehow combine the two tables but nothing works. Can someone please help me?